# onClick move back to main menu in android?

Tags: android, database, authentication, android-activity

I am new bee in Android, so for that I have only limited knowledge in Android. Let me explain in brief about my problem: I have created an `activity` with some fields from where one can fill the fields and clicking `submit` button save on the database...I have a cancel button too, so that when I click on `cancel` button the application should close and move back to main menu i.e. where all the apps icon are displayed. Please HELP .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this for the  [database sample](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/database-crud-tutorial-for-android/).. Then when u have `finish()` in the cancel button `onClick` u can go to the main menu..